# How to get all WebMethods of a WebService pointed by a ServiceReference.Path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, service-reference

In my ASP.NET application, I use the `ServiceReferenceCollection` to carry a set of `WebServices`, and in the code-behind, I'm asked to figure out all the public `WebMethod(s)` and corresponding arguments of the `WebServices` by using .Net Reflection. However, the `ServiceReference` class provides only `Path` information that I can use for reflection, but I don't know how to `GetType()` from `Path`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `ServiceReferenceCollection`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We need some features in ScriptManager, and other functions should be avoided as possible. We're referencing the ScriptManager, and develop our own one.

Comment: I mean why are you using it to find out the webmethods and parameters of the services? Don't limit yourself to that just because you need it for ScriptManager.

Comment: @John, We choose this approach since we'd like to use standard classes as much as possible. But you're right, don't limit ourself. Thanks!

Comment: this particular standard class wasn't designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path` is a path to asmx file.

You can just open this file as a text file.

```
 <%@ WebService
    Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyService.asmx.cs"
    Class="Namespace1.Namepsace2.ClassName" %>
```

Read it as text and parse out class name for the file.
Once you have the class name you can use reflection to iterate through class methods.

Assumed that:

- asmx files are accessible
- web service assembly and types are loaded into app domain

Comment: @Alex: will the .asmx file necessarily be readable if it's in a different project? How would he find the web service class?

Comment: @John Saunders - if you are asking if I know for sure that this solution will work for OP, then my answer is `no`, I don't know. I assumed that all web services in the same project.

Comment: @Alex: your assumption is the reason for my -1.

Comment: @John Saunders - look, I rarely see questions that are completely self-sufficient and clear. I make assumptions all the time. If I have and idea, I would rather share it. Do you suggest that it is better not to answer at all?

Comment: @John Saunders - the -1 itself does not hurt me. Although, your reasoning does. With such a reasoning I could generate hundreds of -1 every day for all kinds of posts.

Comment: @Alex: I suggest that your answers should not contain unstated assumptions. Someone will read your answers, assuming that you intended to be helpful in general, when, in fact, you are only trying to be helpful to the extent that reality meets your unstated assumptions. Either don't make assumptions, or at least, state what they are.

Comment: @Alex: re hundreds of -1. I don't see hundreds of posts that deserve them.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your comments; however, I still can't solve the problem. @John, it's your right to vote up or down. @Alex, I've the same assumption with you, so, I vote you up.

Comment: @William Choi - did you try my idea?

Comment: Tried, but not work. seems that they do not reside in the same assembly.

Comment: @Alex: removed my downvote now that you've stated your assumptions.